# The method 'OutlineButton' isn't defined

Tags: flutter, dart

I know the OutlineButton is Old version
and New version is OutlinedButton.

When I turn into new one then show error[image: Please see my screenshot] in the another padding ,color, shape borderSide.[image: secreenshot]
**Please see my screenshot**

My project:  environment:
sdk: ">=2.11.0 <3.0.0"
module:
androidX: true
dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter
flutter_localizations:
sdk: flutter

And My Insttaled : [√] Flutter Channel stable, 3.0.5,

```
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mvc_pattern/mvc_pattern.dart';

import '../../generated/l10n.dart';
import '../controllers/product_controller.dart';
import '../elements/AddToCartAlertDialog.dart';
import '../elements/CircularLoadingWidget.dart';
import '../elements/OptionItemWidget.dart';
import '../elements/ReviewsListWidget.dart';
import '../elements/ShoppingCartFloatButtonWidget.dart';
import '../helpers/helper.dart';
import '../models/media.dart';
import '../models/route_argument.dart';
import '../repository/user_repository.dart';

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class ProductWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  RouteArgument routeArgument;

  ProductWidget({Key key, this.routeArgument}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ProductWidgetState createState() {
    return _ProductWidgetState();
  }
}

class _ProductWidgetState extends StateMVC<ProductWidget> {
  ProductController _con;

  _ProductWidgetState() : super(ProductController()) {
    _con = controller;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _con.listenForProduct(productId: widget.routeArgument.id);
    _con.listenForCart();
    _con.listenForFavorite(productId: widget.routeArgument.id);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _con.scaffoldKey,
      body: _con.product == null || _con.product?.image == null || _con.product?.images == null
          ? CircularLoadingWidget(height: 500)
          : RefreshIndicator(
              onRefresh: _con.refreshProduct,
              child: Stack(
                fit: StackFit.expand,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 125),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15),
                    child: CustomScrollView(
                      primary: true,
                      shrinkWrap: false,
                      slivers: <Widget>[
                        SliverAppBar(
                          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor.withOpacity(0.9),
                          expandedHeight: 275,
                          elevation: 0,
                          iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                          flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                            collapseMode: CollapseMode.parallax,
                            background: Stack(
                              alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomCenter,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                CarouselSlider(
                                  options: CarouselOptions(
                                    autoPlay: true,
                                    autoPlayInterval: Duration(seconds: 7),
                                    height: 300,
                                    enableInfiniteScroll: false,
                                    viewportFraction: 1.0,
                                    onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
                                      setState(() {
                                        _con.current = index;
                                      });
                                    },
                                  ),
                                  items: _con.product.images.map((Media image) {
                                    return Builder(
                                      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                        return CachedNetworkImage(
                                          height: 300,
                                          width: double.infinity,
                                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                          imageUrl: image.url,
                                          placeholder: (context, url) => Image.asset(
                                            'assets/img/loading.gif',
                                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                            width: double.infinity,
                                            height: 300,
                                          ),
                                          errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error_outline),
                                        );
                                      },
                                    );
                                  }).toList(),
                                ),
                                Visibility(
                                  visible: _con.product.images.length > 1,
                                  child: Container(
                                    //margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 22, horizontal: 42),
                                    child: Row(
                                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                      children: _con.product.images.map((Media image) {
                                        return Container(
                                          width: 20.0,
                                          height: 5.0,
                                          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0, horizontal: 2.0),
                                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                                Radius.circular(10),
                                              ),
                                              color: _con.current == _con.product.images.indexOf(image)
                                                  ? Theme.of(context).accentColor
                                                  : Theme.of(context).primaryColor.withOpacity(0.4)),
                                        );
                                      }).toList(),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SliverToBoxAdapter(
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 15),
                            child: Wrap(
                              runSpacing: 8,
                              children: [
                                Row(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Expanded(
                                      flex: 3,
                                      child: Column(
                                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Text(
                                            _con.product?.name ?? '',
                                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                            maxLines: 2,
                                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline3,
                                          ),
                                          Text(
                                            _con.product?.market?.name ?? '',
                                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                            maxLines: 2,
                                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2,
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Expanded(
                                      flex: 1,
                                      child: Column(
                                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Helper.getPrice(
                                            _con.product.price,
                                            context,
                                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2,
                                          ),
                                          _con.product.discountPrice > 0
                                              ? Helper.getPrice(_con.product.discountPrice, context,
                                                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2.merge(TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough)))
                                              : SizedBox(height: 0),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                Row(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Container(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12, vertical: 3),
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          color: Helper.canDelivery(_con.product.market) && _con.product.deliverable ? Colors.green : Colors.orange,
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24)),
                                      child: Helper.canDelivery(_con.product.market) && _con.product.deliverable
                                          ? Text(
                                              S.of(context).deliverable,
                                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption.merge(TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor)),
                                            )
                                          : Text(
                                              S.of(context).not_deliverable,
                                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption.merge(TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor)),
                                            ),
                                    ),
                                    Expanded(child: SizedBox(height: 0)),
                                    Visibility(
                                      visible: _con.product.capacity != null && _con.product.capacity != "null",
                                      child: Container(
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12, vertical: 3),
                                          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Theme.of(context).focusColor, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24)),
                                          child: Text(
                                            _con.product.capacity + " " + _con.product.unit,
                                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption.merge(TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor)),
                                          )),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(width: 5),
                                    Visibility(
                                      visible: _con.product.packageItemsCount != null && _con.product.packageItemsCount != "null",
                                      child: Container(
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12, vertical: 3),
                                          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Theme.of(context).focusColor, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24)),
                                          child: Text(
                                            _con.product.packageItemsCount + " " + S.of(context).items,
                                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption.merge(TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor)),
                                          )),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                Divider(height: 20),
                                Text(Helper.skipHtml(_con.product.description)),
                                if (_con.product.optionGroups.isNotEmpty)
                                  ListTile(
                                    dense: true,
                                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                                    leading: Icon(
                                      Icons.add_circle_outline,
                                      color: Theme.of(context).hintColor,
                                    ),
                                    title: Text(
                                      S.of(context).options,
                                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1,
                                    ),
                                    subtitle: Text(
                                      S.of(context).select_options_to_add_them_on_the_product,
                                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                               ListView.separated(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                                  itemBuilder: (context, optionGroupIndex) {
                                    var optionGroup = _con.product.optionGroups.elementAt(optionGroupIndex);
                                    print("SIZE:::${_con.product.options.where((option) => option.optionGroupId == optionGroup.id).length}");
                                    return Wrap(
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        ListTile(
                                          dense: true,
                                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0),
                                          leading: Icon(
                                            Icons.add_circle_outline,
                                            color: Theme.of(context).hintColor,
                                          ),
                                          title: Text(
                                            optionGroup.name,
                                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        ListView.separated(
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                                          itemBuilder: (context, optionIndex) {
                                            return OptionItemWidget(
                                              option: _con.product.options.where((option) => option.optionGroupId == optionGroup.id).elementAt(optionIndex),
                                              onChanged: _con.calculateTotal,
                                            );
                                          },
                                          separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                                            return SizedBox(height: 20);
                                          },
                                          itemCount: _con.product.options.where((option) => option.optionGroupId == optionGroup.id).length,
                                          primary: false,
                                          shrinkWrap: true,
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    );
                                  },
                                  separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                                    return SizedBox(height: 20);
                                  },
                                  itemCount: _con.product.optionGroups.length,
                                  primary: false,
                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                ),
                                /*ListTile(
                                  dense: true,
                                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                                  leading: Icon(
                                    Icons.recent_actors_outlined,
                                    color: Theme.of(context).hintColor,
                                  ),
                                  title: Text(
                                    S.of(context).reviews,
                                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                ReviewsListWidget(
                                  reviewsList: _con.product.productReviews,
                                ),*/
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    top: 32,
                    right: 20,
                    child: _con.loadCart
                        ? SizedBox(
                            width: 60,
                            height: 60,
                            child: RefreshProgressIndicator(),
                          )
                        : ShoppingCartFloatButtonWidget(
                            iconColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                            labelColor: Theme.of(context).hintColor,
                            routeArgument: RouteArgument(param: '/Product', id: _con.product.id),
                          ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    bottom: 0,
                    child: Container(
                      height: 150,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 8),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topRight: Radius.circular(20), topLeft: Radius.circular(20)),
                          boxShadow: [BoxShadow(color: Theme.of(context).focusColor.withOpacity(0.15), offset: Offset(0, -2), blurRadius: 5.0)]),
                      child: SizedBox(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 40,
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Expanded(
                                  child: Text(
                                    S.of(context).quantity,
                                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Row(
                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    IconButton(
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        _con.decrementQuantity();
                                      },
                                      iconSize: 30,
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5, vertical: 10),
                                      icon: Icon(Icons.remove_circle_outline),
                                      color: Theme.of(context).hintColor,
                                    ),
                                    Text(_con.quantity.toString(), style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1),
                                    IconButton(
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        _con.incrementQuantity();
                                      },
                                      iconSize: 30,
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5, vertical: 10),
                                      icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle_outline),
                                      color: Theme.of(context).hintColor,
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 10),
                            Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Expanded(
                                  child: _con.favorite?.id != null
                                      ? OutlineButton(
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            _con.removeFromFavorite(_con.favorite);
                                          },
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 14),
                                          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                          shape: StadiumBorder(),
                                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).accentColor),
                                          child: Icon(
                                            Icons.favorite,
                                            color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                                          ))
                                      : MaterialButton(
                                          elevation: 0,
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            if (currentUser.value.apiToken == null) {
                                              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/Login");
                                            } else {
                                              _con.addToFavorite(_con.product);
                                            }
                                          },
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 14),
                                          color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                                          shape: StadiumBorder(),
                                          child: Icon(
                                            Icons.favorite_outline,
                                            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                          )),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(width: 10),
                                Stack(
                                  fit: StackFit.loose,
                                  alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerEnd,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 110,
                                      child: MaterialButton(
                                        elevation: 0,
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          if (currentUser.value.apiToken == null) {
                                            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/Login");
                                          } else {
                                            if (_con.isSameMarkets(_con.product)) {
                                              _con.addToCart(_con.product);
                                            } else {
                                              showDialog(
                                                context: context,
                                                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                                  // return object of type Dialog
                                                  return AddToCartAlertDialogWidget(
                                                      oldProduct: _con.carts.elementAt(0)?.product,
                                                      newProduct: _con.product,
                                                      onPressed: (product, {reset: true}) {
                                                        return _con.addToCart(_con.product, reset: true);
                                                      });
                                                },
                                              );
                                            }
                                          }
                                        },
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 14),
                                        color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                                        shape: StadiumBorder(),
                                        child: Container(
                                          width: double.infinity,
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                                          child: Text(
                                            S.of(context).add_to_cart,
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                            style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                                      child: Helper.getPrice(
                                        _con.total,
                                        context,
                                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4.merge(TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor)),
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 10),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: don't include the whole file code with your question its hard to find which part of the code is causing problem. Try to include that part of code which is causing problem or not working

Comment: As Salaamu Alikum, Thanks for advice

Comment: Wa laikum salam. Try to include information that are specific to your problem. it will help other to solve your problem fast and easily.

Comment: `child: _con.favorite?.id != null
                                      ? OutlineButton(
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            _con.removeFromFavorite(_con.favorite);
                                          },
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 14),
                                          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                          shape: StadiumBorder(),`

Comment: checkout the answer. and let me know if it is working for you or not

Comment: [Another error in this project what I post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73286114/the-android-gradle-plugin-supports-only-kotlin-gradle-plugin-version-1-3-40-and)

Answer (score 0):

The outlinedButton doesnt have the properties like color borderside etc you can give the color and border using style property like.

```
style: ButtonStyle(
backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.green),
),
```

Add the following style to your outlinedButton it will work for you.

```
style: ButtonStyle(
              padding: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 14),
              ),
              backgroundColor:
                  MaterialStateProperty.all(Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
              shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                StadiumBorder(),
              ),
            ),
```